# Change image based on time from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, time

I have an array with values  `var arr = [["imagelink1","0","20"],["imagelink2","21","50"],["imagelink3","51","100"],["imagelink4","101","200"],[null]];`

I get this array from a csv which i can't modify.
First one is an image link 2nd element is start time and 3rd element is end time. I need to call a function with a time value say **display** that will check which time range it falls in and return the image link.

```
function displayimage(timval){  Code here }
```

Calling the function displayimage(22); should check the array and return imagelink2. what might be the most optimized solution to this?

Comment: Shouldn't it return `imagelink2`?

Comment: yes. imagelink2.

Comment: *"I get this array from a csv which i can't modify."* - You may not be able to modify the source CSV, but that doesn't mean you can't (re)structure your array however you like for ease of processing. In any case, why wouldn't a simple loop be an efficient solution? The elements' times seem to be in ascending order, so...just loop and break out as soon as you find the right one.

Comment: JS is an asynchronous language. Provided you are given the schedule per the item to be displayed in advance then you might easily fire `arr.length` many `setTimeout` events to be invoke your display function at appropriate times and forget about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find()` to find sub array where `timval` is between first and second element.

```js
var arr = [["imagelink1","0","20"],["imagelink2","21","50"],["imagelink3","51","100"],["imagelink4","101","200"],[null]];

function displayimage(timval){
  var image = arr.find(e => timval >= e[1] && timval <= e[2])
  return image ? image[0] : 'There is no image';
}

console.log(displayimage(22))
console.log(displayimage(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop should be efficient:

```js
var arr = [["imagelink1","0","20"],["imagelink2","21","50"],["imagelink3","51","100"],["imagelink4","101","200"],[null]];
    
function displayimage(timval){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (timval >= arr[i][1] && timval <= arr[i][2])
      return arr[i][0];
  return null;  // return whatever default value applies for no match
}
    
console.log(displayimage(22));  // imagelink2
console.log(displayimage(222)); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using regular and *fast* `for` loop:

```js
/**
 * Gets an image link if the time value is within a limits
 * 
 * @param timeValue
 * @param arr input array
 * @returns {string}
 */
function displayImage(timeValue, arr) {
    timeValue = Number(timeValue); // casting to number
    var imgLink = "";
    
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i].length === 3  // if it's a valid nested array(of needed length)
           && (Number(arr[i][1]) <= timeValue && timeValue <= Number(arr[i][2]))) {
            imgLink = arr[i][0];
            break;  // avoiding redundant iterations
        }
    }
    return imgLink;
}

var arr = [["imagelink1","0","20"],["imagelink2","21","50"],["imagelink3","51","100"],["imagelink4","101","200"],[null]];
console.log(displayImage("22", arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you

```js
var arr = [["imagelink1","0","2000"],["imagelink2","21","5000"],["imagelink3","51","10000"],["imagelink4","101","20000"],[null]];
displayimage();
function displayimage(){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i].length > 0){
  var image = arr[i][0];
   setTimeout(function(image){
     $(".img").html(image);
    },arr[i][2],image);
 }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img">

</div>
```